# Chef keeps restarting a service when no changes are made to a erb template

Tags: chef-infra

Below is my recipe for installing monit. I am running chef client every 60 seconds to debug.

Chef if restarting monit evry 60 seconds.  No do I stop that?  I thought chef will restart if  change a templete.

```
[Fri, 30 Mar 2012 06:12:18 +0000] INFO: Processing package[monit] action install (monit::default line 5)
[Fri, 30 Mar 2012 06:12:18 +0000] INFO: Processing service[monit] action enable (monit::default line 9)
[Fri, 30 Mar 2012 06:12:18 +0000] INFO: Processing service[monit] action start (monit::default line 9)
[Fri, 30 Mar 2012 06:12:18 +0000] INFO: Processing template[monitrc] action create (monit::default line 14)
[Fri, 30 Mar 2012 06:12:18 +0000] INFO: template[monitrc] mode changed to 644
[Fri, 30 Mar 2012 06:12:18 +0000] INFO: template[monitrc] sending restart action to service[monit] (immediate)
[Fri, 30 Mar 2012 06:12:18 +0000] INFO: Processing service[monit] action restart (monit::default line 9)
[Fri, 30 Mar 2012 06:12:22 +0000] INFO: service[monit] restarted
[Fri, 30 Mar 2012 06:12:22 +0000] INFO: Processing template[monitstart] action create (monit::default line 25)



package "monit" do
  action :install
end

service "monit" do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :start => true,:stop => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end

template "monitrc" do
  path "/etc/monit/monitrc"
  source "monitrc.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
  #notifies :restart, resources(:service => "monit")
  #notifies :restart, "service[monit]"
  notifies :restart, resources(:service => "monit"), :immediate
end

template "monitstart" do
  path "/etc/default/monit"
  source "monit.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
  notifies :restart, "service[monit]"
  #notifies :restart, resources(:service => "monit"), :immediate
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time monit service restarts it changes the file `/etc/monit/monitrc` permission to 600 so only root can read e write it, probably some sort of security reinforcement.

But when your recipe runs it changes the permission to 644, restarting the service which puts the file back with 600. It's like a dog chasing his own tail.

A simple solution would be to change your recipe to apply 600 on the template avoiding the restart.